# Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'

Tags: tensorflow, installation

I recently installed TensorFlow (2.3.1) with CUDA 11.1.0 cuDNN 8.0.4 In many forums, they said cuDNN 11.1 is backwards compatible with the previous versions and I also set the PATH variable as mentioned in TensorFlow installation guide, yet I still get the warning

```
2020-10-05 13:55:42.704300: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-10-05 13:55:42.706817: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

But I do have Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070 Super card. How to fix this issue?
And I am using python 3.8
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no cudnn `11.1` (you mean cuda) and backwards compatibility is also very limited for both cudnn and cuda: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations

Comment: @runDOSrun thanks for noticing, it is cudnn 8.0.4. So you recommend to install the same versions as mentioned in the installation guide of TensorFlow?

Comment: Yes, follow the instructions.

Comment: The version of Tensorflow you have is looking for CUDA 10.1. Yu can leave a newer driver, but you must have the toolkit libraries and CUDNN version which tensorflow was built against

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Tensorflow tested build configurations,`CUDA 11.0` can be used for `TF 2.4.0`

For `TF 2.3.0`, compatible CUDA is `10.1`, cuDNN is `7.6`.

For more details please refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu).